# Where can I find a list of Magic Items by rarity?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am currently looking for a list of Magic Items (non-homebrew and preferably Armor/Weapons) arranged in Common, Uncommon, Rare, Very Rare, and Legendary. There is not one in the Players Handbook or Dungeon Masters Guide that is appropriate.

Does such a list exist and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 14):

There's a [Magic Items by Rarity](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/dnd/MagicItemsRarity.pdf) list in PDF on the D&D WotC website.

Answer (score 6):

The [magic item listing on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items) is both official *and* filterable.

Answer (score 3):

The [5e Magic Items](http://donjon.bin.sh/5e/magic_items/) tool at Donjon is filterable, but not sortable, by rarity and other properties. It may suit your needs.