# Is there a Potions list for Dungeons and Dragons 5th Edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, potions

I have many publications (Starter Set, Players Handbook, DM's Guide, Monster Manual and a couple other Story Books). But I can't seem to locate a table or list of different potions, which I find unusual as D&D is something where potions spring to mind as a very popular choice of item. I'm pretty sure a few of the story books mention different potions (not sure off the top of my head, however), but they certainly mention healing potions.

This is likely just me missing something from one of the books. But, I noticed healing potions are mentioned in the PH. But I'd like to know more about this feature in D&D 5E. Rather than just 1 potion. Or are DMs expected to compose their own ideas of potions?

Comment: [Related] http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73478/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-magic-items-by-rarity

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The DMG lists potions (which are a type of magic item) with the other magic items; the potions are described on pages 187-188.

The [Systems Reference Document](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf) also describes potions, on pages 237-238, and the [*Basic Rules* pdf](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/DnD_BasicRules_2018.pdf) has some of them on page 169.

Answer (score 8):

This [search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items?filter-type=3&filter-search=&filter-requires-attunement=&filter-effect-type=&filter-effect-subtype=&filter-has-charges=) on DnDBeyond provides all the available potions.

The access to each item on this list depends on which manuals one bought on DDB website, but at least one may have the complete list of official potions for DnD 5th-edition.